# How does it affect length of RSA key and size of sent document on time of electronic signaturing using SHA-1 algorithm?

Tags: hash, cryptography

How does it affect length of RSA key and size of sent document on time of electronic signaturing using SHA-1 algorithm?

I used CrypTool to check it, but time of it is this same for even big documents and I don't know if it is problem with CrypTool or maybe I use too small document or something like that?

Comment: Ehm, I think you are trying to say something like this: How does the RSA key size affect the size of a document when using the SHA-1 with RSA algorithm to calculate the signature? Is it correct that the documents grow with the same number of bytes, independent of the size of the document?

Comment: Maybe my english isn't good. I know it. I know that question was stupid too. Who asks, not makes mistakes. :)

Comment: That's not it kspacja, it was implied in the comment that you would *accept the answer* if it was correct, never mind if the question was stupid or not (as somebody took the time to answer it, it was not stupid to them, apparently). Accepting an answer makes it clear it has been solved to other users of the site, and will draw less attention from the good people trying to answer lots of questions. PS will delete this and the other comments on this question later on.

Comment: There also seems to be something about time stamping in the question as well.

Comment: Um yes, sorry I missed that. kspacja, please try and make the question clearer, maybe test the question against somebody in your surroundings who is really good at the English language. I can see you accepted the answer I pointed to and would like to help you, but currently I cannot guess what the question should be.